# API Call in Websocket Handler

Tags: java, websocket, keycloak, vert.x

I need to check if a user delivers a valid token while he request a websocket connection. For the validation a call verification server is necessary. How can I implement it synchronous so that the websocket handler does not end before there was an answer. I am using the vertx framework.

```
server.websocketHandler(ctx -> {
        String clientId = ctx.binaryHandlerID();
        
        oAuth2WebSocket.authenticate(new JsonObject().put("access_token", ctx.query())
                .put("token_type", "Bearer"), authHndlr -> authenticateTokenOverWebSocket(authHndlr, ctx, clientId));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to configure a [Configurator](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html) on the [ServerEndpoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html). Implement the modifyHandshake method and there check for the token. In this method it is possible to modify the headers and indicate if the user does not have the token.

In another approach, in the same method (modifyHandshake), set a variable in the Map obtained from ServerEndpointConfig.getUserProperties() and in the implementation of the handler (Whole for example) to check the variable and respond accordingly.